# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using an L2ARC and a ZIL cache on a RAID 1 or RAIDZ ZFS SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid, zfs

I have a small PC in which an SSD is installed. There is no space for another hard disk in the PC, so in this example the PC really has only one hard disk.

On the hard disk is Ubuntu, which is installed ZFS with a Raid 1 or a RaidZ, which uses partitions or files, instead of usually used multiple partitions. Deduplication and compression is enabled in the case shown.

In the above example, what would be the advantages or disadvantages of adding a L2ARC and a ZIL cache installed in one more partition or one more file on the same disk?

Comment: This is a Q&A (*Question & Answer*) site, and not a forum.  Questions seeking *opinions* are off-topic here, as better suited to a forum. You've outlined no clean *problem* to solve (ie. question) seeking possible answers, but are seeking off-topic *opinions*.  My 2c anyway.   (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of zil and l2arc is that you make them SSDs that are faster than your main spinning rust disk.

If your main disk is already an SSD, then l2arc and zil will gain you nothing.

If they are on the same disk as the main data pool, it will likely decrease both performance and reliability.  These are for multi-disk systems, not single disk systems.